# ssh from cisco with fake source-ip

Tags: cisco, ssh

I have two cisco devices directly connected.

- router1 = 10.70.223.96/31
- router2 = 10.70.223.97/31

on router2 there is an admin ACL `permit 10.64.95.0 0.0.0.255` so I can't only SSH router2 from that range.

How can I **ssh router2 from router1** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure router 1 is advertising connected routes to router 2.
Create a loopback interface on router 1 with an IP in that range.  For example

```
interface loopback 0
ip address 10.64.95.66 255.255.255.255
```

Use the loopback as the source interface for ssh

```
ip ssh source-interface loopback 0
```

Comment: _Make sure router 1 is advertising connected routes to router 2_ , I was missing that step. thanks !